# Finding the lines with the lowest value in their third column given grep results

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep, text-processing

I have a file that consists of lines like this (other numbers included). This is part of the output of

```
$ grep 1848 filename.csv
```

How can I find the top 5 lines which have the lowest third column in the `.csv` file given that 1848 is either in the first or second column?

```
1848,2598,11.310694021273559
1848,2599,10.947275955606203
1848,2600,10.635270124233982
1848,2601,11.916564552040725
1848,2602,12.119810736845844
1848,2603,12.406661156256154
1848,2604,10.636275056472996
1848,2605,12.549890992708612
1848,2606,9.783802450936204
1848,2607,11.253697489670264
1848,2608,12.16385432290674
1848,2609,10.30355814063016
1848,2610,12.102525596913923
1848,2611,11.636595992818505
1848,2612,10.741178028606866
1848,2613,11.352414275107423
1848,2614,12.204860161717253
1848,2615,12.959915468475387
1848,2616,11.320652192610872
```

Unfortunately 1848 sometimes appears in third column as well and I need to ignore that:

```
6687,8963,9.241848677632822
6687,9111,10.537325656184889
6687,9506,11.315629894841848
```

Comment: this is a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann this question is perfectly on topic

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann What makes you think that _this is a question for stackoverflow_?

Comment: ok, my wording might have been a little to strong: What I meant was, it is not directly related to ubuntu and the answers on stackoverflow (and perhaps unix, too) might be more diverse and present even better solutions. This is based on my personal experience, though.

Comment: you are right, though, it is not off-topic.

Comment: There are behavioral differences between bsd and gnu tools, though bash is pretty much the same.  A BSD/Mac user might give you a slightly different (non working) solution, so not 100% specific to Ubuntu, bash is on-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU sort:

```
grep -E '(^1848|^[0-9]{4},1848)' file | sort -t, -k3n | head -n 5
```

(if the first column may have less or more than exactly 4 digits, replace `{4}` with `+`)

Output:

```
1848,2606,9.783802450936204
1848,2609,10.30355814063016
1848,2600,10.635270124233982
1848,2604,10.636275056472996
1848,2612,10.741178028606866
```

Comment: OP mentions that 1848 may occur in the second column, so maybe we need something like `grep -E '(^1848|^[0-9]{4},1848)'`

Comment: @cyrus there are cases that 1848 starts in the second column and I want to include them as well 2606,1848, 8.4507745 for example

Comment: @Zanna what's the complete command? $ grep '(^5785|^[0-9]{4},5785)' imgur_merged_graph.csv | sort -t, -k3n | head -n5 didn't work

Comment: @MonaJalal you need to add the `-E` flag to tell `grep` to use ERE. Complete command `grep -E '(^5785|^[0-9]{4},5785)' imgur_merged_graph.csv | sort -t, -k3n | head -n5`

Comment: can you please provide that as an answer or edit the above? worked! thanks all

Comment: Any time :D nice answer.

Comment: More concisely, use `grep -E '(^[0-9]+,|^)1848,' file`.  No need to repeat the `1848` part.  Also, nothing in that is specific to GNU sort; it's [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

Comment: @Zanna what should we do for 202 not to show 2020 results? this didn't work $ grep -E '(/^202$/|^[0-9]{4},/^202$/)' imgur_merged_graph.csv | sort -t, -k3n | head -n5

Comment: @MonaJalal is there a comma? `grep -E '(^[0-9]+,|^)202,' imgur_merged_graph.csv | sort -t, -k3n | head -n5`?

Answer (score 6):

With just `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} \
          $1==1848||$2==1848 {a[$3]=$0} END {for(i in a) print a[i]}' file.csv
```

- `BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"}` sets the order of any array that will be created according to the index, according to the digits, in an ascending style
- `$1==1848||$2==1848 {a[$3]=$0}` checks if the first or the second field is 1848, if so an then the third field (`$3`) is taken as an array `a` index, with the value being the whole record (`$0`)
- In the `END {for(i in a) print a[i]}`, we are simple iterating over the keys and printing the values

To get only the 5 records, add `head -5` at end:

```
awk ... | head -5
```

Just for the sake of completeness, you can obviously get only the first 5 records by incorporating a tiny `break` logic in the `END` looping, no need for `tail`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} \
          $1==1848||$2==1848 {a[$3]=$0} END {j=0; for(i in a) \
           {print a[i]; j++; if(j==5) break}}' file.csv
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
1848,2598,11.310694021273559
1848,2599,10.947275955606203
1848,2600,10.635270124233982
1848,2601,11.916564552040725
1848,2602,12.119810736845844
1848,2603,12.406661156256154
1848,2604,10.636275056472996
1848,2605,12.549890992708612
1848,2606,9.783802450936204
1848,2607,11.253697489670264
1848,2608,12.16385432290674
1848,2609,10.30355814063016
1848,2610,12.102525596913923
1848,2611,11.636595992818505
1848,2612,10.741178028606866
1848,2613,11.352414275107423
1848,2614,12.204860161717253
1848,2615,12.959915468475387
1848,2616,11.320652192610872

% awk -F, 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} $1==1848||$2==1848 {a[$3]=$0} END {for(i in a) print a[i]}' file.txt
1848,2606,9.783802450936204
1848,2609,10.30355814063016
1848,2600,10.635270124233982
1848,2604,10.636275056472996
1848,2612,10.741178028606866
1848,2599,10.947275955606203
1848,2607,11.253697489670264
1848,2598,11.310694021273559
1848,2616,11.320652192610872
1848,2613,11.352414275107423
1848,2611,11.636595992818505
1848,2601,11.916564552040725
1848,2610,12.102525596913923
1848,2602,12.119810736845844
1848,2608,12.16385432290674
1848,2614,12.204860161717253
1848,2603,12.406661156256154
1848,2605,12.549890992708612
1848,2615,12.959915468475387

% awk -F, 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} $1==1848||$2==1848 {a[$3]=$0} END {j=0; for(i in a) {print a[i]; j++; if(j==5) break}}' file.txt 
1848,2606,9.783802450936204
1848,2609,10.30355814063016
1848,2600,10.635270124233982
1848,2604,10.636275056472996
1848,2612,10.741178028606866
```